# Shopware 6: massively growing cache

Tags: symfony, symfony5, shopware6

We are running a Shopware 6 instance, which is totally fine, takes about 2.9GB of cache and works like a charm.

From time to time, the cache suddenly increases and we have no clue why, like:

```
RC=130 23:24:52 c-2029/app-a ~/exampl.eocm/deployment/current/var/cache $ du -d0 -h

44G .
```

Is there any way to get the info from the cache, what is actually saved? And even better: Where it comes from?

Comment: you could look into the recently created files (`ls` them by created at) to get a clue, but you probably want to see the cache keys / tags which I don't know how to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the http cache there are a bunch of routes and services using the object cache for response or result objects. That would be the second cache layer for things that may not be cacheable by the http cache but can be later on in the stack. There's no index of all of these services and routes as far as I know and they don't implement a common interface. The things they have in common is that they get `cache.object` injected and they are more or less implemented similarly.

Here are some GitHub searches that will give you an overview of most of the routes/services utilizing the object cache:

- [Mostly routes](https://github.com/search?l=&p=1&q=%22%24this-%3Ecache-%3Eget%28%24key%22%20repo%3Ashopware%2Fplatform&ref=advsearch&type=Code)
- [A few more services caching results](https://github.com/search?q=%22%24this-%3Ecache-%3Eget%28self%22%20repo%3Ashopware%2Fplatform&type=Code)

Regarding the cache size:
There are some corresponding improvements coming soon. To just name one off the top of my head there's [this one](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/f37f9a8f63b86ecdf26cf49ad8efcdde6aa669a8) which aims to reduce non-essential entropy in cache keys, thus reducing the cache size.